# Find highest DateTime from list of DateTime's

Tags: c#, list, datetime, max

My Question is that, I want to find the highest DateTime from a list of DateTime?

I have one Array suppose  `string[] btime = new string[100];`

In that Array I am storing the Date which is coming from the SQL-Server
The SQL Query is `[CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),101)]` it is returning the Date in format of **MM/dd/yyyy**
and then after I am concatenating the Date with my own given Time
i.e `.btime[j] = SqlServerDate + " " + 15:20;` and so on;

Now, from this given Array I want to find highest Date and Time

So, I have use this logic

```
string large=""
large=btime[0];

 for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
 {
    if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(btime[i]),DateTime.Parse(large)) > 0)
    {
        large = btime[i];
    }
}
```

but I am getting the Error at

```
if(DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(btime[i]),DateTime.Parse(large)) > 0)
```

The Error is **String not recognized as valid DateTime** This error is occurring because of my System DateTime Format is **yyyy/dd/MM**

So Plz any one can help me in solving this problem
I don't want to change format of the system

Comment: A good demonstration of the advantage of an ISO8601 date format.

Comment: What time are you adding to the date? It must be a valid time format for `DateTime.Parse` function to work. Can you show the content of array, in which format your date is constructed after you append your SQL Server time?

Comment: Have you tried Convert.ToDateTime()?

Answer (score 6):

Others have suggested different ways of parsing the `DateTime`. This seems pointless to me - if you can possibly change the query, just avoid performing the conversion to a string in the first place. The fewer conversions you use, the fewer chances you have for this sort of thing to be a problem.

Change the query so you end up with `DateTime` values, and then finding the latest one is trivial in LINQ:

```
DateTime latest = dateTimes.Max();
```

Answer (score 3):

Hum,

```
// Containing your datetime field
string[] btime = new string[100];

var max = btime.Select(s => DateTime.Parse(s, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Max();
```

Comment: var max = dates.Select(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Max(); this is working for me! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) Method.
Example:

```
CultureProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime.ParseExact(btime[i], "yyyy/dd/MM", provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

you, can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` functionality to do this. Refer the following code part.

```
CurDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Name3, "yyyyMMddhhmmssffff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DateTime.ParseExact() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

```
CultureProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime.ParseExact(btime[i], "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", provider);
```

The second parameter there is the format string. This specifies how your date will be formatted.

Since you are adding a 24 hour time at the end you need the HH:mm (HH says expect a 24 hour time).

Comment: Jon Skeet's answer is the best but I'm leaving this in since it covers the 24 hour time being added to the date.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone.

I have got some sort of answer:

```
string large = "";
large = btime[0];
IFormatProvider culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

// This Code will convert the System Format in Thread, Not the Actual Format 
// of The System
CultureInfo ciNewFormat = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString());
ciNewFormat.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ciNewFormat;

for (int i = 0; i < TimeBackupCounter; i++)
{
    if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(btime[i]),DateTime.Parse(large)) > 0)
    {
        large = btime[i];
    }
}
```